# Publish Messages that are sent from ESP8266 to a Spring boot Java Server using Rabbitmq MQTT

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, mqtt, esp8266

I am new to Rabbitmq.
I want to implement a Spring boot server that gets messages from ESP8266 using MQTT protocol. For this purpose, I am using Rabbitmq as a broker server, but failed to configure ESP8266(using Arduino IDE) to make it publish messages to Rabbitmq.

I am using `PubSubClient`.

```
WiFiClient espClient;    
PubSubClient client(mqtt_server, 1883, callback, espClient);
```

But I am confused about the clientId part, where or how to declare the clientId in Rabbitmq MQTT?

```
client.connect("ESP8266", mqtt_user, mqtt_pass);
```

Comment: Asking for links to guides or tutorials is explicitly off topic for Stack Overflow. Please read the [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on what a good SO question needs, then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69479584/edit) the question to show what you've tried and somebody may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: The question is edited.

Comment: You are still going to need to provide more context to your question. There is not enough here. Under normal circumstances you do not need to tell the broker about the clientid, but they do need to be globally unique (every device needs it's own unique clientid, hard coding it like that is a bad idea unless there will only ever be one client)